# Hidden metadata in TIFF files

Tags: python, data-science, metadata, tiff, imaging

I'm using a proprietary software to record and export microscope images as TIFF files. When I load the TIFF files in the imaging software, I have access to all imaging settings at the time of recording. However, I don't have the software on my working computer, so I'm trying to access the metadata in another way.

I have tried using some online TIFF viewers that display TIFF tags and I've tried the OME metadata viewer using [Bio-Formats](https://www.openmicroscopy.org/bio-formats/). However, both of them show only a part of the metadata that is available through my imaging software. I have also tried accessing the data through [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#image-attributes) to no avail.

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL.TiffTags import TAGS

def main():
    with Image.open('image.tif') as img:
        for key in img.tag:
            print(key)
            try:
                print(TAGS[key])
            except:
               print("unknown key")

            print(img.tag[key])
```

My questions are: Why is the metadata missing, where is it stored, and how can I access it? I'm open to using C++, MatLab, or Python libraries if they can get me what I need.

Comment: What is the proprietary software? Can you share a file?

Comment: There are many reasons why your approach might not work: TIFF can contain multiple images, each with their own tags. Tag values may be pointers to binary data structures elsewhere in the file. A proprietary format may contain metadata not accessible from TIFF structures. Your software may calculate properties from other metadata. The TIFF files may be accompanied by a separate file containing metadata...

Comment: The software is cellSens from Olympus. The metadata I'm interested in is definitely not calculated from other data. To me it seems most likely that the information is stored inside private tags that I can't access with pillow. That's what I concluded after searching online. Given that this approach doesn't work, is there another one I could try? I may find the answer in their docs/manuals.

Comment: I don't know specifically about cellSens, but the following tags are often found in TIFF files saved by Olympus software: 33471 (OlympusINI), 33560 (OlympusSIS), 34853 (OlympusSIS2), and 34665 (ExifTag). The first three are undocumented. [Tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) can partly decode those.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the LEADTOOLS SDK to read the metadata inside your TIFF files. The ReadTags() method offers the ability to read any TIFF tag in the file whether it’s a private tag or not.

The API allows you to enumerate all of the tags in the file, both private and standard, in order to find the tags that you are looking for.
https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/main/clib/working-with-private-tiff-tags.html

See sample code snippet below (Note code snippet is written in C# but APIs for C++ and Java exist too):

```
string tifFile = @"FILE PATH TO TIFF";

using (RasterCodecs _codecs = new RasterCodecs())
{
    CodecsImageInfo _info = _codecs.GetInformation(tifFile, false);
    RasterImageFormat _format = _info.Format;
    IList<RasterTagMetadata> _tags = null;
    if (RasterCodecs.TagsSupported(_format))
    {
       // If you have a multipage TIFF you just enumerate through the pages and pass in the page number in the second param below.
        _tags = _codecs.ReadTags(tifFile, 1);
    }
    else
        return;

    if (_tags != null)
    {
        foreach (RasterTagMetadata tag in _tags)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Id: 0x{tag.Id.ToString("X")}, data length: {tag.GetData().Length}");
        }
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcEY9.png

Feel free to also take a look at the Tutorial links below for more information.
https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/tutorials/cdll-read-and-write-tiff-tags-and-comments.html

DISCLOSURE: I am an employee of the company offering this toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

*Why is the metadata missing*

Note that `TIFF` had multiple versions and also *additional specifications* for example `TIFF/EP` or `TIFF/IT`. Moreover `TIFF` does support so-called **Private** tags, according to [loc.gov](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/content/tiff_tags.shtml)

> An organization might wish to store information meaningful to only
> that organization . . . . Tags numbered 32768 or higher, sometimes
> called private tags, are reserved for that purpose. Upon request, the
> TIFF administrator . . . will allocate and register one or more
> private tags for an organization . . . . You do not need to tell the
> TIFF administrator what you plan to use them for, but giving us this
> information may help other developers to avoid some duplication of
> effort.

Comment: What I don't understand about private tags is, can I not just look up the tags numbered 32768 and above? As far as I understand I may not be able to make sense of them, since I don't know what they stand for but they should show up when I use the code above, no?